# How to properly set favicon for iPhone?

Tags: html, iphone, mobile-safari, favicon

I have generated favicon on *realfavicongenerator.net*, but the favicon is not displayed in Safari on iPhone 6S. I have cleared history and website data, but it doesn't help. Here is my HTML code:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="194x194" href="/favicon-194x194.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href='/favicon.ico' />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href='/favicon.ico' />
```

As you see, I added *rel="icon"* and *rel"shortcut icon"* and also *precomposed* favicon, but nothing helps. I have looked on the Internet and couldn't find a solution. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Full disclosure: RealFaviconGenerator's author speaking.

First, you should run the [favicon checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker) against your site, to spot errors such as invalid URLs.

If the test is positive, you can be confident that your touch icon is configured correctly. You probably have a caching issue, even if you have cleared your browser cache. As a workaround, you can try with another device or wait for a few hours and retry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already checked it and everything is fine. Also have waited hours, but still nothing happened, my iPhone 6S doesn't display it in Safari.

Comment: Could you give me its address for review? You can send me an email to the contact address of RFG

Comment: It's temporary on free hosting, so I'll give you here. [Here is it](http://avok.atwebpages.com)

Comment: Alright so the checker is full-green, but you already knew that. I don't have an iPhone to test it, but my Samsung Galaxy shows the expected icon. Despite of the fact that you have already waited, maybe your phone is still caching the previous icon, really. Let's retry tomorrow or borrow a colleague's iPhone.

Comment: Okay. Let's wait. Thank you!

Comment: Favicon is still not displayed. I tried to reboot my iPhone 6S, but it’s the same. The same situation is with my friends’ iPhone. Maybe it is because of hosting I use? I use awardspace free hosting, because it’s a test website.

Comment: Still no iOS device to check by myself. But I reviewed your code again, everything seems fine... Your hosting is okay, since there is no password restriction or anything... I'm a bit clueless here :-/

Comment: I tried on another (paid) hosting and favicon works there, everything is okay. I don't know why, but I guess that there was something with the free hosting I used before.